# Select substring between characters \x02 and \x0b

Tags: python

I have a string that looks like this:

```
a = '\x02 ciao \n\x0b sdjfip \n\x03 dsfd\ \x02 bella fasfs \n\x0b\x03\n'
```

My goal is to extract the substrings contained within `\x02` and `x0b`which are:

- `ciao \n`
- `bella fasfs \n`

The output substrings should be stored in a list.

So far I tried to use the following line of code

```
import re
result = re.search('\x02(.*?)\x0b', a)
```

but the variable `result` is empty.

What should I do in order to get may result?

Note: `a` is actually a generic string so it could contain more then 2 substrings of interest.

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'\\x02(.*?)\\x0b', a)`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh mmm... I just tried and gives me empty output []

Comment: @PatrickHaugh That causes an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is the newline, not the other chars. Enable `re.DOTALL` to match newline characters:

> If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.

Moreover, to find all the strings (not only the first match object, which is of no interest to you), don't use `re.search`, but use `re.findall`

```
result = re.findall('\x02(.*?)\x0b', a,re.DOTALL)
```

output:

```
[' ciao \n', ' bella fasfs \n']
```

Comment: The output does not really look like to what I am looking for... it must be what is contained between \x02 and \x0b only

Comment: just noticed. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax:

```
re.findall("\\x02(.*?)\\x0b", a, re.I | re.M | re.S)
```

You get empty set because `\n` is special character, and it is not included by default with `.` in search pattern.

Comment: except that it has nothing to do with `\x0b`. It is the `re.M` (multi-line) that made it work, because the pattern contains `\n`. So your code works but the explanation is wrong.